# Identifying this chip in model railroad DCC decoder

Tags: integrated-circuit, identification

Need help in identifying these chips.  They are on a model railroad DCC decoder.  I believe it may be part of the motor control circuitry.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Which one? Also please provide a better photo where the part number is readable. In addition, a zoomed out picture of the surrounding parts is often helpful when determining what kind of IC it is.

Comment: @timmichnay Please give some dimensions or more information about the package.

Answer (score 2):

diode "EN" (SOD323): [PMEG3010CEJ - Nexperia](https://assets.nexperia.com/documents/data-sheet/PMEG3010CEH_PMEG3010CEJ.pdf)

[Taobao](https://www.google.com/search?q=PMEG3010CEJ&tbm=isch&ved=2ahUKEwjX3YXh3tOCAxW9FxAIHbAEBAIQ2-cCegQIABAA&oq=PMEG3010CEJ&gs_lcp=CgNpbWcQAzIECCMQJzIHCAAQgAQQGFC9B1i9B2CICWgAcAB4AIABeYgB5AGSAQMwLjKYAQCgAQGqAQtnd3Mtd2l6LWltZ8ABAQ&sclient=img&ei=8OxbZdelAb2vwPAPsImQEA&bih=914&biw=1866&client=opera&hl=en#imgrc=1SResynFdOPXsM) picture:

[image]

"MFIAV" (TSOP6): [Si3993DV - Vishay](https://www.vishay.com/docs/72320/si3993dv.pdf)

[LCSC](https://www.lcsc.com/product-detail/MOSFETs_Vishay-Intertech-SI3993DV-T1-E3_C145488.html) picture:

[image]

"S8" (SFLAT): [CRS08 - Toshiba](https://toshiba.semicon-storage.com/info/CRS08_datasheet_en_20180718.pdf?did=3168&prodName=CRS08)

[LCSC](https://www.lcsc.com/product-detail/Schottky-Barrier-Diodes-SBD_TOSHIBA-CRS08-T5L-TEM-Q_C5351364.html) picture:

[image]

"9CDG?" : xxx - Onsemi (need better picture please)

"JFN" (XDFN6): [NCV8133BMX150TCG - Onsemi](https://www.onsemi.com/pdf/datasheet/ncv8133-d.pdf)

No picture found but the dot below the marking is typical from Onsemi.

diode "A0 BX" (SMF): [SMF22A - Vishay](https://www.vishay.com/docs/85881/smf5v0atosmf58a.pdf)

[LCSC](https://www.lcsc.com/product-detail/TVS_Vishay-Intertech-SMF22A-HE3-08_C1973936.html) picture:

[image]